# How to pass non utf-8 string from JNI C function to java?

Tags: android, encoding, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use some encoding C function in my Android Java code using JNI.

When I want to return the encoded string, using

```
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, resultStr);
```

I get

```
08-15 13:36:43.787: W/dalvikvm(11302): JNI WARNING: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0x98
08-15 13:36:43.787: W/dalvikvm(11302):              string: '����.y�����s��a'
08-15 13:36:43.787: W/dalvikvm(11302):              in Lorg/wfmu/radio/MainActivity;.xteaBase64Encoding:(Ljava/lang/String;)[B (NewStringUTF)
```

which I guess is due to this xtea algorithm.

So how can I pass the string to Java, and how can I read it?

**java code**

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("mylib");
}

private native String xteaBase64Encoding(String str); 

...

String encodedPlaylistId = xteaBase64Encoding("somestring");
```

**C code**

```
void charToUint32(char *string, uint32_t *block, unsigned int len)
{
        char *blockAsChar = (char *) block;

        for (int i = 0; i < len/4; ++i){
                  blockAsChar[i*4+3] = string[i*4];
                  blockAsChar[i*4+2] = string[i*4+1];
                  blockAsChar[i*4+1] = string[i*4+2];
                 blockAsChar[i*4] = string[i*4+3];
        }
}

void uint32ToChar(uint32_t *block, char *string, unsigned int len)
{
        char *blockAsChar = (char *) block;

        for (int i = 0; i < len/4; ++i){
                 string[i*4] = blockAsChar[i*4+3];
                 string[i*4+1] = blockAsChar[i*4+2];
                 string[i*4+2] = blockAsChar[i*4+1];
                 string[i*4+3] = blockAsChar[i*4];
        }
}

/*
 ** Translation Table as described in RFC1113
 */
static const char cb64[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
/*
 ** encodeblock
 **
 ** encode 3 8-bit binary bytes as 4 '6-bit' characters
 */
void b64encodeblock( unsigned char in[3], unsigned char out[4], int len )
{
    out[0] = cb64[ in[0] >> 2 ];
    out[1] = cb64[ ((in[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((in[1] & 0xf0) >> 4) ];
    out[2] = (unsigned char) (len > 1 ? cb64[ ((in[1] & 0x0f) << 2) | ((in[2] & 0xc0) >> 6) ] : '=');
    out[3] = (unsigned char) (len > 2 ? cb64[ in[2] & 0x3f ] : '=');
}


void encipher(unsigned int num_rounds, uint32_t v[2], uint32_t const k[4]) {
    unsigned int i;
    uint32_t v0=v[0], v1=v[1], sum=0, delta=0x9E3779B9;
    for (i=0; i < num_rounds; i++) {
        v0 += (((v1 << 4) ^ (v1 >> 5)) + v1) ^ (sum + k[sum & 3]);
        sum += delta;
        v1 += (((v0 << 4) ^ (v0 >> 5)) + v0) ^ (sum + k[(sum>>11) & 3]);
    }
    v[0]=v0; v[1]=v1;
}


void xtea(uint32_t *v, uint32_t *k, unsigned int len) {
    for (int j = 0; j < len/8; ++j) {
        encipher(32, &v[j*2], k);
    }
}

jstring Java_***_MainActivity_xteaBase64Encoding(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jstring javaStr)
{

    const char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, javaStr, 0);

    char *key = "abcdefghijklmnop";

    int modSize = strlen(str) % 8;

    int dataSize = strlen(str) + (modSize?(8 - modSize):0);

    char *sourceString = malloc(dataSize);

    memset(sourceString, 0, dataSize);
    memcpy(sourceString, str, strlen(str));
    uint32_t *dataBlock= (uint32_t *) malloc(dataSize);
    memset(dataBlock,0,dataSize);
    charToUint32(sourceString, dataBlock, dataSize);
    free(sourceString);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, javaStr, str);

    uint32_t *keyData= (uint32_t *) malloc(16);
    memset(keyData,0,16);
    charToUint32(key, keyData, 16);

    xtea(dataBlock,keyData,dataSize);

    char *resultStr = malloc(dataSize+1);
    memset(resultStr, 0, sizeof(dataSize+1));
    uint32ToChar(dataBlock, resultStr, dataSize);

    // Base64 encode the string
    int base64Size = (dataSize / 3 + ((dataSize % 3)?1:0)) * 4;

    char *base64Str = malloc(base64Size+1);
    memset(base64Str,0, base64Size+1);

    int j=0;
    int i = 0;
    int bytesRemaining = dataSize;
    while (bytesRemaining > 0){
        b64encodeblock((unsigned char *)&resultStr[j],(unsigned char *) &base64Str[i], bytesRemaining>3?3:bytesRemaining);
        bytesRemaining -= 3;
        j += 3;
        i += 4;
    }

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, resultStr);
}
```

Comment: You should be aware of the character set and encoding that you are using. Encryption and Base64 re-encoding are just transformation layers over the original. Both the producer and consumer of the string must agree on all three. Java strings are Unicode. `GetStringUTFChars` converts a string to a 0-terminated, modified UTF-8 encoding. `NewStringUTF` reverses it. Unless the consumer is aware of that, it won't get the same result over the full range of Unicode characters. Only JNI-related libraries understand modified UTF-8 encoding. Other libraries _get by **if** the data is a Unicode subset._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which I guess is due to this xtea algorithm

If you're trying to create a string from *encrypted data*, just don't. Either convert it to base64, or pass it to Java as a byte array and do the conversion there.

Encrypted data is *not* text, and should not be represented "raw" in a `String`.

The fact that your function is called `xteaBase64Encoding` suggests that you should be converting it to base64, too. Indeed, it looks like you're already *trying* to do base64 encoding - it may be that you just need to change this:

```
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, resultStr);
```

into

```
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, base64Str);
```

Currently you're not *using* `base64Str` after populating it...

(It's not clear why you're doing this in native code anyway - have you benchmarked and found that XTEA is too slow in Java?)

Comment: I obvously had to pass base64Str, thanks. I tried in Java but didn't get the same result as the examples my client passed me. Since I didn't want to get into the algorithm, I'm using his code, which is C code.

Comment: @jul: Hmm... I think it's at least worth investigating why the results of the encryption were different. Using the client's code, you may just be delaying finding a problem which will bite you later.